# Advice on implementing a garbage collector in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, garbage-collection

I'm working on a toy programming JavaScript-like language which I'm writing in Rust, and this language has a very basic mark and sweep garbage collector. I have a working prototype, and the way I implemented it is to wrap Rust objects which are going to be allocated on the GC heap inside of a `Box`. Then I can get a pointer to the GC'd object and wrap pointer into a dynamically-typed `Value` type, i.e.:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Value
{
    Int64(i64),
    UInt64(u64),
    HostFn(HostFn),
    Fun(*mut Function),
    Str(*mut String),
    Nil,
}
```

These are the values which my bytecode interpreter works with. The [full source code is here](https://github.com/maximecb/kavascript/blob/f3472aab3cdf977d89ba00cfafc0f67481ecd0b9/vm.rs) if anyone wants to see more about how the GC works and provide feedback. I'm trying to keep the implementation as simple as possible so that this will be beginner-friendly.

What I would like advice with is that working with mutable pointers like this in Rust is very unergonomic. Every time I want to dereference them, I have to wrap everything in `unsafe`. This means, if I want to implement string concatenation or equality, I have to wrap the whole thing in an unsafe block where I'll dereference and borrow both strings. I have to do the same thing if I want to implement function calls. That's going to result in `unsafe` blocks everywhere in the implementation of my interpreter.

So my question is: can we make this more ergonomic somehow? One potential idea would be to have a helper method on `Value` that can return a `&'static mut String` for example. This is essentially lying to the Rust compiler about lifetimes for the sake of convenience, because the programmer still needs to be careful that GC'd values are on the VM heap, otherwise they will be collected. Would this be safe though? The real danger would come if the Rust compiler were to reorder operations around. Advice welcome.

Comment: Why do you have pointers for some but not the others? Is there a reason it's not `Str(String)` so the string is owned, and the equivalent for whatever the owned version of `Function` is?

Comment: The reason they are pointers is because otherwise, whenever you pass a value around, you'd have to copy a potentially large object. String and Function objects live on the GC heap and are shared. The HostFn type is a host/runtime function, which is basically a Rust function pointer.

Comment: It looks like you made them pointers so you could derive `Copy`. I wouldn't do that. Stick with `Clone`, ditch `Copy`, and use a managed smart pointer type such as `Str(Arc<Mutex<String>>)` or `Str(Gc<Mutex<String>>)` or what have you.

Comment: Or wrap all `Value`s in a smart pointer like `Gc<Mutex<Value>>`, and use simple owned types inside like `Str(String)`. I can't tell where you intend the GC pointer to go.

Comment: Using ref counting kind of defeats the point IMO. It's also quite a bit less efficient. The interpreter would lose quite a bit of speed.

Comment: Right, use `Gc` if you've got your own GC smart pointer type.